# Changing confirmation style when deleting files in dired

Tags: dired

In aquamacs, the confirmation to delete files from dired is a y or n, and immediately on pressing one of them the file is deleted (no RET required after the y or n).

In emacs, the confirmation is yes or no, so that I need to type the full yes or no plus RET afterwards.

I would like to change emacs so that it behaves like aquamacs.

Is this possible at all?  I did a google search plus checked M-x customize-group RET dired RET and couldn't find anything that helped (I found stuff to get rid of the confirmation altogether, but that's not what I am after).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```el
(setq dired-deletion-confirmer #'y-or-n-p)
```

Note that *recursive directory deletion* hard-codes a `yes-or-no-p` because it's a more dangerous action.

Comment: Thx for reminding people about the reason for `yes-or-no-p`, and about `dired-deletion-confirmer`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the *dirty* and *unsafe* hack, which is used widely:

```
(fset 'yes-or-no-p #'y-or-n-p)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: Vivi: Are you quite sure about that? xuchunyang isn't kidding about the "unsafe" bit. `yes-or-no-p` is typically as far as Emacs goes when it comes to making *really sure* you definitely want to do that destructive thing you asked it to do. Clobbering that function with `y-or-n-p` for any and all use-cases is not generally recommended, as it makes it extremely easy to tap away at the `y` key without actually reading the prompts properly (and hence without noticing that one of those questions wasn't actually what you assumed it was going to be).

Comment: You could also use an alias: `(defalias 'yes-or-no-p 'y-or-n-p)`

Comment: @suvayu Right, maybe `defalias` is easier to understand for newcomers?

Comment: @phils OK, I get it now. This answer will change all confirmations to y or n when I only wanted to change it for file deletion (as I have an option to throw deleted files to my system trash, so in case of mistake I have a backup). I don't think it is right to change this for all the other cases as I could possibly do something I didn't mean to. Thank you for your warning.

Comment: @xuchunyang I will change the accepted answer to the answer that does what I wanted (without impacting on the other stuff). I am still thankful for your answer and I still think it could be useful for someone that happens to bump into this site.