# How to force Yes/y answer to `emacs has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway?` prompt

Tags: auto-save, prompt, save

I am working in a `git-repo` using `zsh` shell.

On the background, [git-auto-fetch](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/git-auto-fetch) plugin is running in order to automatically fetch all changes from all remotes while I am working in a git-initialized directory.

Due to this, if the buffer I am using in `emacs` is touched or changed the file behind my back:

- I am first asked:
  `emacs has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway?` 
  #> Yes
- Than asked again:
  `example_file.py changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)`
  #> y

---

Would it be possible to prevent:

- `emacs has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway?`
- `example_file.py changed on disk; really edit the buffer? (y, n, r or C-h)`

messages to show up by default and force to make their answer `Yes`/`y`?

---

my save function:

```
(defun my-save-all ()
       (interactive)
       (let ((message-log-max nil)
             (inhibit-message t))
         (save-some-buffers t)))

(defun save-all ()
  (interactive)
  (my-save-all)
  (bk-kill-buffers "__init__.py")
  (bk-kill-buffers "*helm"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing confirmation style when deleting files in dired](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16891/changing-confirmation-style-when-deleting-files-in-dired)

Comment: There are also other questions closely related:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/22569/105.
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/17269/105

Comment: Would it be possible to apply `Changing confirmation style when deleting files in dired ` into save file cases? @Drew

Comment: I guess not. Sorry; I misunderstood your question, and thought it was more or less asking for how to do `(fset 'yes-or-no-p #'y-or-n-p)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check the [`auto-answer` package](https://github.com/YoungFrog/auto-answer/blob/master/auto-answer.el). It works on functions whose the underlying prompt is `yes-or-no-p`, `read-string`, `read-from-minibuffer`, `read-key-sequence`, `read-key-sequence-vector`, `read-event` , `read-passwd` or lastly `read-multiple-choice`.

It's pretty easy to use. Just bind `auto-answer` to a list of `(REGEXP ANSWER)`:

```
;; Example usage:
;; (let ((auto-answer '(("\\`What's your name\\? \\'" "jack")
;;                      ("\\`What's your password\\? \\'" "secr3t"))))
;;   (list
;;    (read-string "What's your name? ")
;;    (read-passwd "What's your password? ")))
;; => ("jack" "secr3t")
```

Hence, in your case, you could do something like this (not tested):

```lisp
(let ((auto-answer
       '((".*has changed since visited or saved. Save anyway\\?" t)
         (".*changed on disk; really edit the buffer\\?.*" ?y))
     ...
)))
```

I have read the source code of `save-some-buffers`, so I'm sure that the first prompt is a `yes-or-no-p` (thus the answer `t`), though it's rather obvious. I'm not sure about the second prompt, but it is most likely a `read-multiple-choice`. If not, you have to figure it out and change the answer accordingly.

`auto-answer` is currently not on Melpa. You can install it with [quelpa-use-package](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa-use-package):

```lisp
(use-package auto-answer
  :quelpa (auto-answer :fetcher github :repo "YoungFrog/auto-answer")
  :ensure t)
```

or just with quelpa (which is available on Melpa):

```lisp
(quelpa '(auto-answer :fetcher github :repo "YoungFrog/auto-answer"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to install auto-answer from package-install?

Comment: @alper It's currently not on Melpa, but you can install it with [quelpa-use-package](https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa-use-package). See the update of the answer.

Comment: it says: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Package ‘auto-answer-’ is unavailable")` while using quelpa

Comment: @alper My bad, quelpa-use-package is not on Melpa, but `quelpa` is. I also assumed you have installed `use-package`. With quelpa alone, `(quelpa '(auto-answer :fetcher github :repo "YoungFrog/auto-answer"))` should work. Is that what you tried ?

Comment: I gave up `quelpa ` and just created its file under a folder and loaded using: `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/auto-answer")
(require 'auto-answer)
`

Comment: I verify that `(quelpa '(auto-answer :fetcher github :repo "YoungFrog/auto-answer"))` also works

Comment: @alper Yeah, that is faster. I also have issue with `quelpa` in the past...

Comment: After applying this solution, once in a while emacs freezes. Do you think would it be possible that `auto-answer` does not respond back and emacs just endlessly waits response .

Comment: @alper It's unlikely as `auto-answer` replace the prompt function call by the answer whenever a regexp matches the prompt or call the prompt function as before, otherwise. So, at best, there is less function calls; at worst, it's the same as before. Moreover, `auto-answer` cannot loop endlessly, as it only loops on the `(regexp . answer)` alist and potentially the `read-multiple-choice`'s alist. You might want to debug it to find where the problem arises exactly.

Comment: Like I am using in emacs-daemon, and respone is not entered in minibuffer as `y` or `n` I cannot write any character into the buffer. I just assume in some cased auto-answer might not apply `y` or `n` which leads emacs daemon to halt.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an example from the [emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/YesOrNoP), the following works for me to force Emacs to overwrite external changes to the file:

```
(defadvice basic-save-buffer (around auto-confirm compile activate)
  (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'yes-or-no-p) (lambda (&rest args) t))
            ((symbol-function 'y-or-n-p) (lambda (&rest args) t)))
    ad-do-it))
```